# Jaxb strategy for testing large document mappings

Tags: java, jaxb

We are working with Jaxb to unmarshall a large deeply nested document. Xjc wouldn't work with the schema so we are having to map it by hand. Any suggestions for testing strategies here?

I think I would like to to write mapping tests for each nested class as I go, ideally with using small XML fragments rather that many variants of full documents. However I don't see how to do this due to namespace problems. This is a fragment I would like to validate:

```
<responsibleParty>
    <gmd:individualName>
        <gco:CharacterString>Someones name</gco:CharacterString>
    </gmd:individualName>
</responsibleParty>
```

I don't see much of a way to do this. Any suggestions for strategies here?

Thanks!

Comment: Yikes!  Why didn't xjc work on the schema?  An automated tool is definitely the best choice here!  You're better off fixing the XSD than trying to write a test case to cover every boundary condition...

Comment: The schema is set by other groups, so I can't fix it, tho I am not sure it is broken. I worked through the binding mappings so I can get XJC to run. However the resulting code won't compile, the schema uses recursive nesting, xjc can't seem to deal with that. I hit this problem [https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9259888] I haven't tried to map this by hand yet to see if can be dealt with at all.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem you are seeing is due to nested classes having the same name as parent classes as per the link you provided:

- https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9259888

Then you can workaround this issue by using an external bindings file:

**recursive.xml**

The binding file allows you to rename the nested classes to avoid the name conflict.

```
<jaxb:bindings 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.1">
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="recursive.xsd">
        <jaxb:bindings node="/xsd:schema/xsd:element[@name='topic']/xsd:complexType/xsd:sequence/xsd:element[@name='topic']/xsd:complexType">
            <jaxb:class name="Topic2"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:bindings node="/xsd:schema/xsd:element[@name='topic']/xsd:complexType/xsd:sequence/xsd:element[@name='topic']/xsd:complexType/xsd:sequence/xsd:element[@name='topic']/xsd:complexType">
            <jaxb:class name="Topic3"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

**recursive.xsd**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="topic">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="topic" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="topic" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="topic" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**XJC call**

The binding file is specified in the XJC call:

```
xjc -d out -b recursive.xml recursive.xsd
```

**Topic (Generated Class)**

```
package generated;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "topic"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "topic")
public class Topic {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected Topic.Topic2 topic;

    public Topic.Topic2 getTopic() {
        return topic;
    }

    public void setTopic(Topic.Topic2 value) {
        this.topic = value;
    }

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "topic"
    })
    public static class Topic2 {

        @XmlElement(required = true)
        protected Topic.Topic2 .Topic3 topic;

        public Topic.Topic2 .Topic3 getTopic() {
            return topic;
        }

        public void setTopic(Topic.Topic2 .Topic3 value) {
            this.topic = value;
        }

        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
            "topic"
        })
        public static class Topic3 {

            protected List<String> topic;

            public List<String> getTopic() {
                if (topic == null) {
                    topic = new ArrayList<String>();
                }
                return this.topic;
            }

        }

    }

}
```